# How to find owner of a file on a different client?

Tags: perforce

I want to find the name of the owner of a file that is on a different client on perforce:

```
p4 filelog <filename>
```

But I'm getting the following prompt

> file(s) not on client.

Answer (score 0):

`file(s) not on client` means you used a local path that doesn't correspond to a depot file that's synced to *your* current client, and therefore doesn't resolve to any file that's known to Perforce.

If you want to make a query about a depot file that's not synced to your current client, use a fully qualified depot path, e.g.:

```
p4 filelog //depot/main/some_file
```

The full depot path will always resolve to the depot file regardless of current client state.

If you want to find out where (or whether) a depot file is synced to your own client, you can do:

```
p4 have //depot/main/some_file
```

and if you want to find out what revision of a file *another* client has, you can use the client as a revision specifier (just like a label):

```
p4 files //depot/main/some_file@SOME_CLIENT
```